# Configure IPython to interactive mode by default

Tags: ipython

I've attempted to read the IPython 0.13 docs, but I've been unable to figure out how to get IPython to default to interactive mode.

Back in IPython 0.10, I could type:

```
ipython <some_script.py>
```

and the script would run and drop me to the interactive prompt.

Today, with 0.13, I must add the `-i` command-line option:

```
ipython -i <some_script.py>
```

Can someone please share the ipython config file option that would make IPython 0.13 go directly to interactive mode after running a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. create default IPython config files first, if you haven't already

   > ipython profile create
2. add this line to profile_default/ipython_config.py (you can find profile_default with `ipython locate profile`)

   > c.TerminalIPythonApp.force_interact = True

Which is the value that `-i` sets at the command-line.
With this config, it will be as if you always type `ipython -i`.