# Ditch the Out[] prompt in ipython

Tags: ipython, prompt, gedit

I'm using the excellent [Gedit IPython plugin](http://www.cogsci.nl/software/gedit-ipython-plugin) and finding I have a minor frustration with it. If I run some code right in the console, I get results and a new `In [1]:` prompt. If I run code from gedit with ctrl-r, I see results but I'm stuck in an `Out [1]:` prompt. I have to hop over to the terminal and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

```
In [1]: def get_soup(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
    return soup

Out[1]:
```

I tried tweaking my [`force_interact` settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209530/configure-ipython-to-interactive-mode-by-default) but that doesn't seem to change anything. How do I persuade ipython-listener to give me a new `In` prompt after I run code from gedit?

Comment: force_interact is for running files from the command line when you start IPython. This sounds like it might be a bug in the plugin.

Comment: If you don't need to use your output cache, you can always just disable Out entirely, with the --cache-size=0 option to iPython.

Comment: @cge launching w/ `ipython-listener --cache-size=0` doesn't change anything.

Comment: @ThomasK I think you're right. Plugin (in its current state, here: http://paste.debian.net/72141/)